# Tax calculation in new extension

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I've developed an extension to calculate shopping cart/order amount based on special formula and requirements. The following code snippets override setRowTotal method, and work correctly:

```
$this->setRowTotal( $totalAmount );
$this->setBaseRowTotal( $totalAmount );
```

Should I use the following methods to calculate Tax? If yes, how I should use them?

```
$this->setRowTotalInclTax( $rowTotalInclTax );
$this->setBaseRowTotalInclTax( $baseRowTotalInclTax );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to Tax configuration setting, tax rate was not correct. My following code is correct:

```
$requestTax = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')
   ->getRateRequest()
   ->setProductClassId($product->getTaxClassId());

$taxRate = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')
   ->getRate($requestTax);
```

With $taxRate, the following code can solve this issue:

```
$totalAmountInclTax = $totalAmount + ($totalAmount/100) * $taxRate;

$this->setRowTotalInclTax( $totalAmountInclTax );
$this->setBaseRowTotalInclTax( $totalAmountInclTax );
```